# get month of year from Calendar class of java

Tags: java, calendar

I wrote simple java program in which I get **day of month**, **days in month** and **month**

**see below code :**

```
//Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
log.info("day of month: "+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
log.info("days in month: "+calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
log.info("month: "+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Running above code I get this **output**:

```
day of month: 7
days in month: 31
month: 2
```

But when I put below statement

```
log.info("month: "+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

before

```
log.info("day of month: "+calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

I get **this output**: (which is what I want)

```
day of month: 7
days in month: 31
month: 5
```

Can any body help me understand why I get `month: 2` ?

Comment: This isn't clear.  If you swap the lines around, your output should be in a different order.  Please post the *real* output.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Youre setting the `Calendar` field to `Calendar.MONTH` ([value 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)) here

```
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                               ^
```

You can do this

```
calendar.set(2014, Calendar.JUNE, 1);
```

although the Month 5 is June (since month field starts from 0 for `Calendar`) which only has 30 days

Comment: i want to use system year, month and day that's why i put `Calendar.MONTH` which might be `June` or `5`

Comment: The field you are using are meant as field numbers rather than actual values. If you want the system year just leave the value in the `Calendar` _as is_ and just [`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int)) the day & month

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code of `Calendar.java` of JDK.

```
  public final static int MONTH = 2;
```

Here, `Calendar.MONTH = 2, Calendar.YEAR=1 and Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH = 5`. You set these constant value to calender using set method like.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                 |              |              |
                 1              2              5
```

Comment: whats `1`,`2`and `5` ?? `Calendar.MONTH = 2` = `MARCH` ??

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()
    .getDayOfMonth()
```

…and…

```
YearMonth.from(
    LocalDate.now()
).lengthOfMonth()  // .getMonthValue()  .getYear()
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the industry-leading *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

#### Parts

Interrogate for the parts as needed.

```
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;
int month = ld.getMonthValue() ;
int year = ld.getYear() ;
```

### `YearMonth`

To work with the month as a whole, use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

Ask for length of month.

```
int lengthOfMonth = ym.lengthOfMonth() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).